# How do I replace lines after using counter on them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, collections

I have been struggling to figure out a way to replace lines from the collections counter that I do not want in the final outcome. Here is the coding:

```html
from collections import Counter

print("Enter lines that you need counted.")
contents = []
def amount():
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        contents.append(line)

    return
amount()



count = Counter(contents)
print(count)
```

When you input anything, lets say the number 4, it will come out like "Counter({'4': 1})". I am trying to remove some of the characters in the output, such as "{" and " ' ". I tried `count = [item.replace('{', " ") for item in count]` but it seems to make it so the counter no longer works. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Those aren't in the value, it's just the printed representation of a `Counter` object. Loop over the items in the dictionary and format the output how you want.

Comment: @Barmar which dictionary are you referring to?

Comment: A Counter is a type of dictionary. The keys are the things it counts, the values are the counts.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own formatting code by looping over the items in the counter.

```
print(', '.join(f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in count.items())
```

`count.items()` returns a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs from `count`.

`f'{key}: {value}'` is an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) that formats the key and value with `:` between them. This is used in a generator that returns the formatted string for each pair returned by `count.items()`.

`', '.join()` concatenates the values in the sequence of formatted strings with `,`  delimiters between them.

Comment: Do you mind explaining this a little further in detail for me? I am very new to python and still learning everything.

Comment: I've updated the answer with explanations of each part.

Comment: I have been trying to insert the - print(', '.join(f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in contents.items()) - into the code but it keeps throwing me " AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' ", do you have any reason why?

Comment: @Camol That's because *contents* is a list and not a dictionary or any other object with an associated *items()* method

Comment: I see what u mean, do you know of any ways to fix this or make contents into a dictionary?

Comment: I used `contents` where I meant to use `count`.